# Explain why $f$ doesn't have a max or min at $x = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

How would you solve the following problem?

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is thrice differentiable and $f'(0) = f''(0) = 0$ and $f'''(0) = 2$. Show that $f$ cannot have a maximum or minimum at $x=0$.

I tried to use the mean value theorem to prove that for the interval $[a,b]$ where $a < 0, b> 0$ we get $f''(b) > f''(a)$, and by the intermediate value theorem we get $f''(b) > 0$ and $f''(a) < 0$, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to solve it.

How do we actually characterize a point being a maximum or a minimum when the function is thrice differentiable? I know that if a local min/max occurs when the first derivative is zero? For higher orders do all of the derivatives have to equal zero?

Comment: Do you know about third-degree Taylor polynomials?

Comment: Ohh yes - is it something like, if you let $f$ be continuous on the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$ you can use Taylor series to obtain a result like $f(x) - \frac{x^3}{3} \geq f(0)$ for $x \in (-\delta,\delta)$, which implies it is not a max or min?

Comment: What you've written is incorrect. If $P$ is the third-degree T.P. at $0$, then you know that $f(x)=P(x)+\epsilon(x)$ where $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\epsilon(x)}{x^3}=0$.

Comment: Re your last paragraph: Consider $f_n(x)=x^n$ for various $n\in \Bbb N.$

Answer (score 1):

$(f'')'(0)=f'''(0)>0$ so there exists $r>0$ such that $f''(x)<f''(0)<f''(y)$ whenever $-r<x<0<y<r.$

Since $f''(0)=0$, we have $f''(x)<0$ when $-r<x<0$ and $f''(y)>0$ when $0<y<r.$

So $f'$ is strictly decreasing on the interval $(-r,0),$ and hence $f'$ is strictly decreasing on $(-r,0].$ (See Footnote 1). And we have $f'(0)=0.$ So $f'(x)>0$ when $x\in (-r,0).$ So $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-r,0),$ and hence $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-r,0].$(see Footnote 2).

A similar analysis of $[0,r)$ shows that $f$ is also strictly increasing on $[0,r).$

Therefore $f$ is strictly increasing on $(-r,r).$

Footnote 1. If $x\in (-r,0)$ and $f'(x)\le f'(0)$ then $\frac {1}{2}(f'(x)+f'(0))=f'(x')$ for some $x'\in (x,0)$ because $f'$ is continuous. But then $-r<x<x'<0$ with $f'(x)\le f'(x'),$ contrary to $f'$ being strictly decreasing on $(-r,0).$

Footnote 2. If $x\in (-r,0)$ and $f(x)\ge f(0)$ then for some $x'\in (x,0)$ we have $f(x')=\frac {1}{2}(f(x)+f(0))$ because $f$ is continuous. But then $-r<x<x'<0$ with $f(x)\ge f(x'),$ contrary to $f$ being strictly increasing on $(-r,0).$